# Strange thread in Centos Server

Tags: centos, security, threads

There is a strange thread called sourplum running in my CentOS server. It uses a lot of resources and affects the excel and pdf generation.

```
Tasks: 280 total,   2 running, 277 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 51.6%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 47.3%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8030792k total,  6821428k used,  1209364k free,   892256k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,    36712k used,  4157588k free,  3776380k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13170 root      20   0  613m 3544  964 S 402.1  0.0   2595:58 sourplum
25664 focu      20   0  384m  21m  14m R  9.9  0.3   0:00.65 php
 4377 root      20   0  129m  22m 3780 S  2.0  0.3   0:48.58 MONyog-bin
    1 root      20   0 19348 1372 1136 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.13 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.42 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.12 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 stopper/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.24 migration/1
```

and that there are two files of this name located

```
/sourplum
/root/sourplum
```

But I was not able to find out anything regarding what this process is.

I tried to kill the thread but it started again automatically. I have to restart the server but it is just a temporary fix. After several hours the thread start again.

What should I do? Can I just delete the file? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/0687cd8d38c334a970b81b1ba9bb2e18aa66424edba3f33b61f7d03e35d5db20?environmentId=300

Comment: @user449299 What should I do to remove it?

Comment: If it is malware then the general advice here is nuke it from orbit, rebuild and restore from a known good backup.